# string to datetime.datetime type format

Tags: python, datetime

I'm getting date input from user. It's coming to me as string object and I can't do any operation on it.

I couldn't change my string to datetime object with datetime library.

```
24th of May 2016        04:00
```

How can I convert this string to a `datetime` type?

Comment: No I idea for date formatting. %b %d %Y or more. I didn't try anything :/ @Tanu

Comment: Further to  @Tanu: you may want to read the help on `mcve` (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil), it will chew that string up no problems:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('24th of May 2016        04:00')
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 24, 4, 0)
```